# Facebook share does not preview (full) page

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

When I use the facebook share button on my website it does only show the website title but not the content of the page I share. Can't find a solution on the web.

I use the code from the facebook developers website

And I replaced the data-href for the button with my page URL: i.e. http://www.strongbase.nl/verslagdetail/2

But when I click the share button it only shows this (see screenshot below):

Is there a way to fix this?

http://puu.sh/dQDGZ/76817d30de.png

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: facebook code from facebook developer website:

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement some metatags.

Look here: http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

So for example, in head:

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Your pagetitle here"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://urltoyourpage.com"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://linktosome.com/image.png"/>
</head>
```

You can add more properties. Just google OpenGraph, or click on the provided link.